# Is there an easy way to calculate $\Big(1-\frac{n}{4}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{n}{5}\Big)\dots \Big(1-\frac{n}{30}\Big)$ for any integer $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an easy way to calculate $$\Big(1-\frac{n}{4}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{n}{5}\Big)\dots \Big(1-\frac{n}{30}\Big)$$ for any integer $n$. I tried to expand, but it seems a lot of troubles.

Comment: It's certainly easy for $n=4,5,\ldots,30$ :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen forgot to say, n is not any of the value 4,5,...30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $1 - \frac{n}{4}$ as $\frac{4 - n}{4}$; do this for each term, and see whether you notice a pattern. You can simplify to a quotient of factorials. Of course, to compute those may take some work, but for an approximate value, Stirling's approximation might suffice.

Oh...also pretend that your whole product is multiplied by $(1 - n/1) (1 - n/2) (1 - n/3)$, and then divide by that at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I was overthinking the problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>30$, this can be rewritten as $$ -\frac{(n-4)!}{(n-31)!\cdot 30!}$$
if that helps ...